# Perl Regex .. Simple if statement

Tags: regex, perl

I'm working on a Perl function (or should I say sub-routine?) and am relatively new to Perl (and regular expressions).

The whole thing works except for one simple part... an if statement that needs to use a regular expression.

I need to check if a string:

- begins with optional white-space
- after the white-space contains 0 or 1 instances of a string enclosed in square brackets.. (i.e. [test])

The regular expression I've written is `^\s*{\[$testString\]}?$`

This is not working.  However, I haven't been able to get this to work with regular expressions at all, so I'm wondering if I'm doing it correctly.

Right now the test case I'm working with, the string I want the if to be true on is `[fallback_test]`.

When I do

```
if ($string eq ' [fallback_test]')
```

then it works.  However, if I do

```
if ($string =~ /fallback_test/)
```

then it doesn't enter into the if block like it should.  Ideally, it will use the regular expression I've written:

```
^\s*{\[$testString\]}?$
```

So my questions are...

- Why are the regular expressions not working for me?
- Is that regular expression going to do what I want when I get the regex's to work properly in this block?

Comment: You have some other problem. The regex `/fallback_test/` is perfectly fine and will match. `$string` isn't what you think it is if it does not match.

Comment: Craig says the if block is not executed if he uses the matching expression. Another possibility is that the if block is executed, but behaving differently because of side effects of the matching expression. For example his if block might use one of the special variables that is changed by a matching expression.

Comment: It may be something like this.  Basically when I add in the regex my whole program hangs and I can't figure out what the problem is..

Comment: @Craig - if `^\s*(?:\[$testString\])?$` is causing you problems, then something in $testString is like metachars. They have to be escaped beforehand or change the regex to `^\s*(?:\[\Q$testString\E\])?$` or `^\s*(?:\Q[$testString]\E)?$`. You might want to read up on what metachars are first.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have something like: `my $testString = "fallback_test";`

Try: `/^\s*\[${testString}\]?$/`

Comment: Why? `/fallback_test/` is just fine.

Comment: @BrianRoach: that isn't his question.  His requirements are bulleted.  That's just a simpler test case he did, which he said failed.

Comment: I suggest Re-reading his question. The issue isn't with a regex at all if /fallback_test/ doesn't match

Comment: @BrianRoach: Understood the question from the git-go, `That's just a simpler test case he did, which he said failed`.  The above should be right, his regex had misplaced `{}`, however, you are correct... he has something else wrong, other than the regex. --- still the regex was the question, not what else could be wrong, since he did not show enough.

Comment: *Which would not fail if $string was what he thought it was*. You can tell him to use any regex in the world, and it won't match either.

Comment: @BrianRoach: it may not match, but he asked for a set of criteria `I need to check if a string... [-] begins with optional white-space [-] after the white-space contains 0 or 1 instances of a string enclosed in square brackets.. (i.e. [test])`.  It's specifically about regex, and the above should work, if it doesn't, there is something else going on.

Comment: (Just saw your edit, and I get it ... it just won't help the OP to have a perfect regex if his input is mangled in the first place, and he'll keep coming back and telling you it didn't work)

Comment: @BrianRoach: I totally agree with that :) as you stated under the question... something else is going on.  I think you should post that as an answer - I'll upvote it :)

Comment: Um.. thanks.  I'll look to see what else is wrong.  Also appreciate the help with the regex.  I will report back.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group optional string. Here's working example:

```
$string =~ /^\s*(?:\[.*?\])?$/;
```

And here's perl oneliner to test:

`perl -e 'die "not matched!" unless " [fallback_test]" =~ /^\s*(?:\[.*?\])?$/'`

Explanation:

In regexp `(subpattern)` groups subpattern and stores matched result in $1..$9 variables.
`(?:subpattern)` groups subpattern, but not stores matched result nowhere.
`.*?` will match all characters till first ']' character. You may want to replace this with your test string like 'fallback_test' or 'test', or some regular expression you to satisfy you requirements.

Also note that this regexp will match an empty line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Your answer and other answers above are all coming up with a similar problem on the other strings that shouldn't match...

Invalid [] range "e-d" in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^\s*(?:\[test text [more text <-- HERE more text]\])?$/

Comment: @Craig square brackets in your sample look wrong. '[' and ']' are special symbols in regexps and should be escaped if you want to match them.

Answer (score 0):

So a grouping is needed instead of {}?, use ()?.

FWIW your regex will only match 4 distinct combinations since you have anchored the
line on boundries with ^$ and have 2 optional subexpressions.

1 '' the empty string
2 '    '  all whitespaces
3 '[string]' just [string]
4 '  [string]'  whitespaces followed by [string]

If this is just fact finding in a single regex, you can always capture both
subexpressions and test later for the result that is meaningfull to you.

For example:
**edit** adding quotemeta to regex

if ($str =~ /^(\s*)(\[\Q$testString\E\])?$/) {
..test $2 for the string
..test $1 for leading spaces

But if [string] is required, a better regex would be
`/^(\s*)\[\Q$testString\E\]$/`, then test $1 if it contains optional whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding curly brackets in your regex? they are used for stating the number of repetition e.g., `/\d{5}/`.

To do what you want it should be like:

```
$string =~ m/^ ?(?:\[\Q$testString\E\])?$/
```

`\Q...\E` should save us from runtime errors when a metacharacter could be interpreted in the regex.

Take into account that the regex you are asking for will match empty lines too unless you mean it.